# Ionic framework + Google material design, which framework to use?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, material-design, materialize, ionic-material

I really want to use Ionic Material Design into my app. I am currently using Ionic Material: http://ionicmaterial.com/
It is really easy to use and it work great sometime but not the others. It is little bit buggy on the actual devices and it is NOT PRODUCTION ready (and I am using it on a production app...)

I heard someone has success with Ionic Material - http://materializecss.com/
But is this play well with Ionic? I heard it need jQuery. Does jQuery play well with Ionic? (never combine these 2 together...since jQuery is evil and why we use Ioinc + AngularJS the first place...correct me if I am wrong of this opinion...)

And there is other option out there. And I heard a lots of painful stories Angular Material with Ionic...anyone agree?

I just want to find the best framework before I dive myself into modification. I will start a poll if I can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the Ionic Material tool much, but agree it is primarily a fun dev tool and not ready for production (not that it might be eventually, but its certainly not as field tested as Ionic itself).

Can Ionic and jQuery work together? Sure. Its really can Angular and jQuery work together, since Ionic leverages Angular. Its common to use jQuery with Angular (Angular itself uses a subset of jQuery already, and will use the entire jQuery version if it is found on the page.) jQuery is not evil, the prolific use of jQuery for simple things that can be done without jQuery is what people often refer to as 'evil'. Think of it like loading jQuery just to use it for 5 lines of JavaScript that could have been written without jQuery to begin with.

You can also look at Angular Material (https://material.angularjs.org) for a Google backed project that was actually built with help from the Ionic team. However, it is not Ionic and not finished either. I use it in my projects though haven't used it much on mobile yet (it is designed to meet Material Design spec, which is designed for all platforms).

Lastly, you could just use Ionic. There are some customizations you can make, and I don't know what your vision is exactly, but I think it is the most robust option for hybrid apps today.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) without any problems. jQuery is mandatory but I did not have any problems with it. I also tried [muicss](https://www.muicss.com/) but I had some issues on the iPhone 6 with the button animation.